# AMCharts 5. Change series bullet color

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

I want to change the label bullet color if it is outside of a column.

```
const series = chart.series.push(
  am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
    xAxis,
    yAxis,
    name: "Test",
    valueXField: "time",
    categoryYField: "category",
  })
);

const columnTemplate = series.columns.template;

columnTemplate.setAll({
  cornerRadiusTR: 4,
  cornerRadiusBR: 4,
});

series.bullets.push(function () {
  return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
    locationY: 0.5,
    locationX: 0,
    sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {
      text: "{valueX}",
      fill: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
      centerY: am5.p50,
      paddingLeft: 4,
      populateText: true,
    }),
  });
});
```

For example, '8' must be black, because it's outside the column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8QfZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the function which creates the bullets you should be able to add the parameters
`root, series, dataItem`

Then you can access the specific data point / item and change something dynamically.

Like so (untested code):

```
series.bullets.push(function (root, series, dataItem) {
  const useBlack = dataItem.dataContext.valueX < 10; // use the "valueField" here, maybe it's "time" directly?

  //  const color = useBlack ? 'black' : 'white';
  const color = useBlack ? root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText") : root.interfaceColors.get("text");

  return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
    locationY: 0.5,
    locationX: 0,
    sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {
      text: "{valueX}",
      fill: color,
      centerY: am5.p50,
      paddingLeft: 4,
      populateText: true,
    }),
  });
});
```